# Mysql query dies on second SET statement

Tags: php, mysql

In the following code:

```
<?php
require_once('/var/cbinfo_connect.php');
$delete_statement1 = "DELETE FROM cbdata";
$delete_statement2 = "DELETE FROM CATstudent";

mysqli_query($dbc,$delete_statement1);
mysqli_query($dbc,$delete_statement2);
$import_statement1 = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/scripts/cbinfo.csv' INTO TABLE cbdata FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (deviceID,activeTimeRanges0activeTime,activeTimeRanges0date,activeTimeRanges1activeTime,activeTimeRanges1date,annotatedAssetID,annotaedLocation,annotatedUser,bootMode,deviceFiles0createTime,deviceFiles0downloadUrl,deviceFiles0name,deviceFiles0type,deviceFiles1createTime,deviceFiles1downloadUrl,deviceFiles1name,deviceFiles1type,ethernetMacAddress,firmwareVersion,@var1,@var2,macAddress,model,notes,orgUnitPath,osVersion,platformVersion,recentUsersemail1,recentUsers0type,recentUsersemail2,recentUsers1type,serialNumber,status)
SET lastEnrollmentTime = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%Y-%m-%D %H:%i:%s')
SET lastSync = STR_TO_DATE(@var2,'%Y-%m-%D %H:%i:%s')";
$import_statement2 = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/data/CATS Export.txt' INTO TABLE CATstudent FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";

mysqli_query($dbc,$import_statement1);
mysqli_query($dbc,$import_statement2);

?>
```

Everything works correctly except the second SET command in $import_statement1.  If I move the "; up to the first line and comment out the second SET statment, it works correctly.  If I try to comment out the first line leaving everything as is, the import fails.  I don't have any way currently to debug the code.  I have changed the first SET statement to the settings of the second and it works.  For some reason it will not process the second SET statement whatever it is.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: _"I don't have any way currently to debug the code."_ - then I don't see how you would be able to _fix_ the problem either (if you had access to the script to fix it, then you'd have access to insert debug statements, too, right?), so I'll guess we'll just have to wait ... until the opportunity arises for you to make that minimal first effort.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: I have figured out that the issue is directly tied to the MYSQL statment, it has noting to do with PHP.  That's one hurdle that I''ve crossed.  By running the LOAD DATA INFILE command directly in mysql, I get a syntax error on the second SET.  Thanks for any suggestions so far.  I know I have a lot to learn about coding.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query` takes one statement and only one statement at a time. You should split this up, make sure that each statement completes successfully, then and only then move on to the next statement.

If you're dealing with a situation where you have to run N queries to get the right result, storing those queries in an array and then iterating through that array, executing each while paying attention to success/failure codes, makes for minimal, maintainable code.

The other problem here is the syntax of your [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) query. There's only one `SET` section allowed:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/scripts/cbinfo.csv' INTO TABLE cbdata FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (...)
SET lastEnrollmentTime = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%Y-%m-%D %H:%i:%s'),
    lastSync = STR_TO_DATE(@var2,'%Y-%m-%D %H:%i:%s')
```

Adjusting that query to have two assignments in the singular `SET` block should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I don't that that's the cause here as it's failing through the singe query.  $import_statment1 will run successfully, as long as I don't include the second SET command.

Comment: The way your code was formatted made it look like those `SET` operations were independent, but they were actually part of the `LOAD DATA INFILE` call. Edited to include more information here about that specific failure.

Answer (score 0):

Issue found, diagnosed as a MYSQL error, did not need the second SET command, instead one SET and the two expressions after it followed by a comma.  Thanks for any suggestions.